# Rendering ng-content multiple times

Tags: angular

I want to create table with data but last column should be user defined with `ng-content`

Something like this:

```
<my-component [columns]="columns" [data]="data">
    <div>last column</div>
<my-component>
```

`MyComponent.ts`

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of columns">{{row[cell}}</td>
        <td><ng-content></ng-content></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Problem is that last column's content is rendered only once - in last row.
How to fix it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with ng-content. Try this:

table.component.ts

```
@Input() tpl: TemplateRef<any>;
```

table.component.html

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of columns">{{row[cell}}</td>
      <td>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"></ng-container>
       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<my-component [columns]="columns" [data]="data" [tpl]="lastColumn"><my-component>

<ng-template #lastColumn>
  <div>last column</div>
</ng-template>
```

With that being said I would take a look at [Angular Material CDK table](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview) before implementing my own. You might save a lot of time that way.

Comment: That works - thanks. I'm using CDK but I need this anyway.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Good solution. I do not like angular tables, a bit hard to customize, I tried using them but when I had to insert extra span columns I had some difficutiles.